# Color coding list query

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, spcolor

I have a document library for recording daily IT security checks and I would like to color a row if a checkbox for the column 'Monthly' is checked? (YES)
As it displays 'YES' on the list view, I only want the 'YES' in the column 'Monthly' to activate the color coded row.

Comment: Why don't you use JSLink for this.

Comment: I could but I've not found best solution to implement this.

Comment: I would check http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/ which I believe will cover your needs.